# Поиск элемента во вновь открытом окне

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Идет обращение к сайту:

```
driver.get("http://site_adress");
```

Далее осуществляется поиск элемента и его нажатие:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"4d4fa89c-b0b7-45e0-9e4f-202d27b55541\"]/input[1]")).click();
```

Данный элемент открывает в новом окне личный кабинет пользователя. Теперь необходимо выполнить нажатие кнопки "Редактировать" в личном кабинете:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]/div/a[1]")).click();
```

Но элемент кнопки редактирования не обнаруживается. Я так подозреваю, что поиск он осуществляет на первом открытом окне. Как можно исправить данный момент?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого используй такой метод, как `driver.switchTo().window(String windowHandle)`

Получить список со всеми доступными хенделами : `driver.getWindowHandles()`

После того, как ты сделал

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"4d4fa89c-b0b7-45e0-9e4f-202d27b55541\"]/input[1]")).click();
```

переключись на нужный тебе window, и делай `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]/div/a[1]")).click();`